# I am facing some problems in this R shiny wordcloud

Tags: r, shiny

I am working on shiny app for wordcloud

SERVER code::

```
library(shiny)
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  wc_data <- reactive({
    
    input$update
    
    isolate({
      
      withProgress({
        setProgress(message = "Processing Corpus...")
        wc_file <- input$wc
        if(!is.null(wc_file)){
          wc_text <- readLines(wc_file$datapath)
        }
        else
        {
          wc_text <- "A word cloud is an image made of words that resembles a cloud shape"
        }
        
        docs <- Corpus(VectorSource(wc_text))
        inspect(docs)
      })
    })
  })
    wordcloud_rep <- repeatable(wordcloud)
    output$wcplot <- renderPlot({
    withProgress({
                  setProgress(message = "Creating Wordcloud...")
                  docs1 <- wc_data()
                  wordcloud(docs1, min.freq = 100, colors = brewer.pal(8, "Set1"), random.order = F, rot.per = .30)
    
    })
  })
})
```

UI code:

```
library(shiny)

ShinyUI<-fluidPage(
                  titlePanel("Word cloud"),
                   sidebarLayout(
                     sidebarPanel(
                      fileInput("wc", "Upload a TextFile for creating a word cloud", multiple = F, accept = "text/plain"),
                      actionButton("Update", "Create a word cloud")
                    ),
                    mainPanel(
                      plotOutput("wcplot")
                      )
                  )
            
)
```

My word cloud is not being displayed
i have tried an i think the button of create wordcloud is not able to rerun the code and not accepting the file uploaded

Comment: I believe you want `input$Update` (capital 'U') in your `reactive` expression. This will match `ui`. Also, you could consider replacing with `eventReactive(input$Update, {})` if this will be triggered by the `actionButton`.

Comment: Thank You so much. Just a capital U and I did made a new project from scratch with different method as I had to submit. Anyway thanks for the help.